# fail during optimization via cross validation with XGBoost

Tags: r, cross-validation, xgboost, mlr

I run a random search cross validation for the XGboost regression via mlr package. My setup:

```
library('mlr')
library('xgboost')

train.task <- makeRegrTask(data = train_data, target = "target")
test.task <-  makeRegrTask(data= test_data, target = "target")

lrn <- makeLearner("regr.xgboost")
lrn$par.vals <-  list(
              objective="reg:gamma"
             ,eval_metric= "mae"
             ,early_stopping_rounds = 10
            )


#set parameter space
params <-  makeParamSet(
   makeIntegerParam('max_depth', lower=3L, upper = 15L )
  ,makeNumericParam("min_child_weight",lower = 1L, upper = 10L)
  ,makeNumericParam("subsample",lower = 0.5, upper = 1)
  ,makeNumericParam("colsample_bytree",lower = 0.5, upper = 1)
  ,makeNumericLearnerParam("eta", lower=10/ntrees, upper = 0.3 )
  ,makeIntegerParam('nrounds', lower = 10L, upper = 2000L)
)

#set resampling strategy
rdesc <-  makeResampleDesc("CV", iters=3L)

#search startegy
ctrl <-  makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 150L)

#parameter tuning
mytune <- tuneParams(learner = lrn
                     ,task = train.task
                     ,resampling = rdesc
                     ,measures = mae
                     ,par.set = params
                     ,control = ctrl
                     ,show.info = T)
```

This calculations were running well until the 113 parameters' combination, where as the MAE value, I get "NaN": presented below

```
[288]   train-mae:0.964692 
[289]   train-mae:0.964503 
[290]   train-mae:0.964989 
[291]   train-mae:0.965080 
[292]   train-mae:0.965028 
[293]   train-mae:0.964473 
[294]   train-mae:0.964592 
[295]   train-mae:0.964647 
[296]   train-mae:NaN 
Error in if ((maximize && score > best_score) || (!maximize && score <  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Any ideas what could go wrong?

Comment: Have you tried running xgboost directly on your data? Could be that it's a problem with that (e.g. missing values).

Comment: Its not unheard of that some hyper parameter combinations are not able to generate a "working model" on all data sets. Perhaps you should look into [`configureMlr(on.learner.error = "warn")`](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/configureMlr.html)

Comment: Are you sure the line `makeNumericLearnerParam("eta", lower=10/ntrees, upper = 0.3 )` does what you intend to?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff yes. Initially I was doing grid search cross validation and based on the best values running xgboost on my data - no  any issues. And such issues as missing values/wrong data format I've controlled beforehand.

Comment: @missuse thanks, i will check these two options.